# Is there any way that a Chaincode can interact with outside entity?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm writing a Hyperledger-fabric chaincode. And I wish it can get some strings from outside program and send some messages to it. I want to know if the chaincode can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do so. This practice is called "oracles". Read [this](https://blog.oraclize.it/launching-the-oraclize-service-on-hyperledger-fabric-c336c2d7d9b1?gi=262ec4586736) for example.

But it is highly not recommended to do so for several reasons (ChainCode best practice: [Accessing external resources (http) might expose vulnerability and security threats to your chaincode. You do not want malicous code from external sources to influence your chaincode logic in any way. So keep away from external calls as much as possible.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503153/best-practices-to-follow-while-writing-hyperledger-fabric-chaincode))

Answer (score -2):

In order to interact with outside programs you need to set up a blockchain **oracle**. The oracle should return deterministic results to all endorsers - otherwise endorsement fails. It is crucial that all endorsers have access to this outside program, for example through an API.

The commercial blockchain oracle provider [Oraclize](https://oraclize.it) offers integration with Hyperledger Fabric. You can check out their [connector chaincode](https://github.com/oraclize/fabric-api/blob/master/connector/oraclize-connector.js) to see how they integrate the oracle with Fabric and follow a similar approach.

Edit: To be clear, I am not in any way affiliated with Oraclize nor do I want to advertise for them. I just named them as an example since they are well known and offer integration with Hyperledger Fabric

Comment: Well next time dont just copy my answer and post it but maybe comment on mine if you want to say the same and point something important out...

Comment: That's pretty rude man. I started typing the reply when the original question had zero replies. I only saw your reply when I revisited the page later on

Comment: I have just zero understanding for copying answers and posting them. This seemed so obvious and let me assume this. When you didn't intend to do so then my apologies! But pls check back next time if there's already the same exact answer you want to provide and if it is delete yours (if you dont provide any other useful info) or comment on the initial answer.

Comment: I definitely didn't intend to, I'm sorry if I offended you. I think my answer still contains some additional info (endorsement failure, connector chaincode), so if you want to integrate that in your answer, I'll gladly delete mine